# MySQL 5.5 - view all queries executed on certain table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I need to explore queries, which were executed on certain table.

For example, in Oracle we could investigate the `V$SQL_TEXT`, maybe something similar exists in MySQL 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

- The "general log", if turned on, records all queries touching all tables.
- The "slow log", if turned on with `long_query_time=0`, records all queries, plus performance-related info, for all tables.

In either case, you would need to filter down to the desired table.  This cannot be done with a simple `grep` since the log formats involve multiple lines of text.  Still, it is better than nothing.

(There is no feature of MySQL to monitor a single table or database or user.  This Answer applies to all(?) versions of MySQL.)